# App update rejected because of REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

Our app update got rejected by Google because we had REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES in the Manifest. We removed it, uploaded a new version and it still got rejected. We then added

```
 <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:node="remove"/>
```

as suggested here on SO, but to no avail. We continue to get rejected.
There is no REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES in our Manfiest and not in the Merged Manifest either.
What are we missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have a version uploaded in alpha/beta/internal channel. Try to update that too.

Comment: The problem was indeed a 2-years old version in the closed channel. That's why an app update in the production channel was rejected! Rather unbelievable, and when this is so, it would have been more than helpful if they had added that information in the mail they send out

Comment: yeah it is really frustrating and their communication is sometime not very clear regarding these.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED:**

Remove the permission from your manifest and in-app functionality.
Double check that your app is compliant with all other Developer Program Policies.
Sign in to Play Console and submit the update to your app.
Alternatively, you may also choose to deactivate these versions to avoid additional enforcements that could occur. You may follow the given steps to deactivate the non-compliant app bundles or APKS:

1. Go to your Play Console.
2. Select the app.
3. Go to the track where the non-compliant APK or app bundle is.
4. Near the top right of the page, click Create new release. (You may need to click Manage track first) If the release with the violating APK is in a draft state, discard the release.
5. Under the new release page, you can choose to: **A) Upload a new, compliant APK/app bundle and make sure the new release is rolled out 100% to completely deactivate the non-compliant APK.**  B) Not upload any new APK/app bundle (publish an empty release to just deactivate the non-compliant old version).
6. Regardless of what you choose in step 5, please make sure that the non-compliant version of APK/app bundle is under the Not included section of this new release. For further guidance, please see the "Not included (app bundles and APKs)" section in the Play Console Help article.
7. To save any changes you make to your release, select Save.
   When you've finished preparing your release, select Review release.
8. If the non-compliant APK is released to multiple tracks, repeat steps 3-8 in each track.